# InvalidArgumentError while running my Rnn model on tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is the error:

> InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [] [Condition x == y did not
>   hold element-wise:] [x
>   (loss/dense_13_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape_1:0) = ]
>   [64 1] [y
>   (loss/dense_13_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/strided_slice:0)
>   = ] [64 60]    [[node loss/dense_13_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal/Assert/Assert
>   (defined at
>   C:\Users\Enock\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751)
>   ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_50507]
>
> Function call stack: distributed_function

and, this is the code:

```
filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models\{}.model".format(filepath), monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,         save_best_only=True, mode='max')
```

How to resolve it? i dont know where am going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2737

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience, this happens due to two reasons:

1. Either your last layer dense with softmax activation does not have the necessary number of neurons.
2. The way you pass the labels or the labels are not correctly defined for your problem.

The issue is that I/anybody cannot help you anymore if we don't have any code provided apart from these two lines --- your error will not be solved if you show us only these lines from above.

Comment: i have done as instructed and posted the code and error